# Why/ How do some manufacturers remove the Encryption option?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, encryption, manufacturers

I've owned two Android tablets now - one a no-name cheapo device (running 4.1.1); the other a more mainstream Asus Memopad HD 7 (4.2.1).  Neither have had the "System" -> "Security" -> "Encrypt Data" option; that is,  the option is simply *not there*, rather than being present but greyed out.

I'm really disappointed and, above all, bewildered by this: what motivation has a company for removing such a useful feature when it comes built into stock Android? What other devices have people used that don't have this feature?

<strike>As an addendum: does anyone know of any e-mail clients that will encrypt all your e-mail and passwords *as they are written to disk*, so that if the device falls into "enemy hands", as it were, they won't be able to read them, even if they have root access? I'm thinking specifically as a workaround for the confusing lack of whole device encryption, here.</strike>

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking lots of questions at once here, and not all your questions are suited to this site's format. "What other devices have people used that don't have this feature?" doesn't have an objective answer, so it's not really suitable here. Your question about email clients sounds too much like an app recommendation. We don't tend to accept such questions, because they are heavily opinion-based, and the answers go out of date very quickly as apps come and go, and add and remove features.

Comment: To get better answers, I suggest you split your addendum into a separate question, and rephrase it as, "How do I keep my email and passwords secure without full-device encryption?" That way, you're opening it up to answers that aren't just about an app.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, Dan - I'll definitely split off a "How do I keep my email and passwords secure without full-device encryption?" question, but would also really like a list of other devices that don't support encryption.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but it may be for certain variants of the device that go to countries covered by U.S. munitions export regulations. Strong encryption counts as a munition for the purpose of the regulations, so this feature might have been left out to allow the device to be sold in such countries. Even if the manufacturer is not from the U.S., the Android software comes from there, so it's still covered by the regulations.